# How do I export data from a table to a xml file?

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, oracle11g, export-to-xml

I want to export data to a xml file from oracle. I'm not sure how to go about it. This is the code for what I have tried so far but I am getting a error saying table doesnt exist. The schema has select privilege for the table and also the table is in the same schema selected. Stuck on this while. Any help would be appreciated

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xmlUnload (ulSchema IN VARCHAR2, ulTable IN VARCHAR2, ulDirectory IN VARCHAR2)
IS
    l_file          UTL_FILE.file_type;
    xml_data        VARCHAR2(5000);
BEGIN
    SELECT dbms_xmlgen.getxml('SELECT * FROM '||ulSchema||'.'||ulTable) xml INTO xml_data FROM dual;

    l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(ulDirectory,ulSchema'.'ulTable, 'w');

    UTL_FILE.putf(l_file, xml_data);
    UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
END xmlUnload;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the owner of the table is not the same as the owner of the procedure, you're probably running into a case of definer vs invoker rights.

As stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authorization.htm):

> How Roles Work in PL/SQL Blocks The use of roles in a PL/SQL block
>   depends on whether it is an anonymous block or a named block (stored
>   procedure, function, or trigger), and whether it executes with
>   definer's rights or invoker's rights.
>
> Roles Used in Named Blocks with Definer's Rights All roles are
>   disabled in any named PL/SQL block (stored procedure, function, or
>   trigger) that executes with definer's rights. Roles are not used for
>   privilege checking and you cannot set roles within a definer's rights
>   procedure.

Note that it's talking about "definer's rights procedure" there.

You could try setting the procedure to use invoker rights (the user that is executing the procedure) and see if this resolves the issue:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xmlUnload (ulSchema IN VARCHAR2, ulTable IN VARCHAR2, ulDirectory IN VARCHAR2)
AUTHID CURRENT_USER -- options are "CURRENT_USER" or "DEFINER"; DEFINER is the default
IS
    l_file          UTL_FILE.file_type;
    xml_data        VARCHAR2(5000);
BEGIN
    SELECT dbms_xmlgen.getxml('SELECT * FROM '||ulSchema||'.'||ulTable) xml INTO xml_data FROM dual;

    l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(ulDirectory,ulSchema'.'ulTable, 'w');

    UTL_FILE.putf(l_file, xml_data);
    UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
END xmlUnload;
```

Check out the details on the invoker_rights_clause here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_procedure.htm#i2065815